# Vertices WON'T move along axis

Tags: vertices, axis

Okay, so I have this problem I can't seem to find anyone else who does. So I'm trying to move a loop of vertices on the Z axis (First pressing G, then Z) but the problem is that it only LOOKS like it's moving up, but when I rotate the camera it's moved in some odd direction instead. I've also tried inputting the amount I want in to move via the keyboard instead of with the mouse, with the same issue. I've tried this from every angle, to no avail. Any help is much appreciated.[image: This is what it looks like when I pull the vertices up]

[image: This is what it looks like rotated 90 degrees][image: And from the bottom]

Comment: You have snapping enabled (magnet icon).

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented by @RobertGützkow, you have Snapping enabled:

[image]

That means your vertices will be snapped to the closest face while moving them. You can disable it altogether or hold CTRL while moving.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but thank you! This was such a massive headache for me.